# Use login tables created by Django from NestJS/NodeJS service

Tags: node.js, django

We have the secrets and the source code from Django project (this is not a hack topic) this is a topic about the posibility of use Django generated tables for Users Login BUT from NodeJS/NestJS service.

The goal is kickout Django, and keep existing users to generate same JWT tokens from encrypted password coming from users table generated by Django.